# 'Nested model form' adds new fields properly, but coffeescript behavior does not impact new fields like existing fields on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am using a nested model form as in rails cast.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised - here is the add_fields coffeescript:

```
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    $(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()
    event.preventDefault()
```

I have a set of three radio buttons( "excel" + "video" + "multiple choice") and a hidden div associated with each.  When I click on a radio button 'video', a few forms pop out in a div named .videoCreator.  The same behavior for 'excel' and 'multiple_choice'.

```
$(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()
  $(".stepRadio").change ->
    $(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()
    $container = $(@).closest('.stepCreator')
    $container.find(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()
    if @value is "video"
      $container.find(".videoCreator").show()
    else if @value is "excel"
      $container.find(".excelCreator").show()
    else if @value is "multiple_choice"
      $container.find(".mcCreator").show()
```

The behavior is fully illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2XAP2/

My problem is that the behavior above no longer works for the newly added fields when I click on the .add_fields button, and new forms are dynamically created.  I click on the add fields button - a new set of radio button pops out, but, when I click on any of the three radio buttons it does not display the associated div (keep in mind that I hide all three divs, on the click of the add fields button - if I don't hide them then all three divs appear at once).   However on any other field on the page, it works properly (just not on the fields that were just added).

I tried combining the two behaviors as below, but that did not work:

```
$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
        time = new Date().getTime()
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
        $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
      $(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()
      $(".stepRadio").change ->
        $(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()
        $container = $(@).closest('.stepCreator')
        $container.find(".excelCreator, .videoCreator, .mcCreator").hide()
        if @value is "video"
          $container.find(".videoCreator").show()
        else if @value is "excel"
          $container.find(".excelCreator").show()
        else if @value is "multiple_choice"
          $container.find(".mcCreator").show()
        event.preventDefault()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you just need to use the "live" version of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

instead of directly binding to `change`. Something like this:

```
$(document).on 'change', '.stepRadio', ->
  # Same stuff you have in your .change callback
```

instead of your current:

```
$(".stepRadio").change ->
  #...
```

This form of `on` watches for events on `document` and the change events (including those from newly added elements) will bubble up to `document` where `$(document).on('change', '.stepRadio', ...)` will see them.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Xk5ZC/

Hit the *Add more* button to add another section and you'll see that all the radio buttons keep working. Note that the demo doesn't properly patch up the radio button `id` attributes or the `for` attributes on the `<label>`s, a real life version would take care of that but this is just a demo and I didn't want to clutter it more machinery that was needed to demonstrate the usage of `on`.